# Fastest way to search for whole words in 20mb flat file database (PHP)

Tags: php, search, flat-file

I have 20MB flat file database with about 500k lines, only `[a-z0-9-]` characters are allowed, average 7 words in line, no empty or duplicate lines:

Flat file database:

```
put-returns-between-paragraphs
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
```

I'm searhcing for `whole words only` and extracting `first 10k results` from this db.

So far this code work ok if the 10k matches are found in let's say first 20k lines of the db, but if the word is rare, the script must search all 500k lines and this is 10 times slower.

Settings:

```
$cats = file("cats.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$search = "end";
$limit = 10000;
```

Search:

```
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    if(preg_match("/\b$search\b/", $cat)) {
        $cats_found[] = $cat;
        if(isset($cats_found[$limit])) break;
    }
}
```

My php skills and knowledge are limited, I cannot and don't know how to use sql, so this is the best I can do it, but I need some advices:

- Is this the right code to do it, foreach and preg_match are problem?
- Should I split large file into smaller files, if yes what sizes?
- And in the end, will sql be faster and how much? (Option for the future)

Thanks for reading this and sorry for bad English, this is my 3rd language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **most** of the lines don't contain the searched word, you could execute `preg_match()` less often, like so:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // fast prefilter...
    if (strpos($line, $word) === false) {
        continue;
    }
    // ... then proper search if the line passed the prefilter
    if (preg_match("/\b{$word}\b/", $line)) {
        // found
    }
}
```

Though, it requires benchmarking in practical situation.

Comment: yes, only 5 searched words will contain 30% of the lines, other words will contain from 1-5000 lines. strpos is very fast, but it cannot find whole words only, that's why i'm using regex with word boundaries

Comment: Edited comments in my above code to be more explicit. Also, you definitely have to benchmark with these 5 slowest words, 30% is quite considerable.

Comment: ok i've tested adding strpos before preg_match, it's 2 times faster searching for most of the words like "automatic", because it will find 100 lines out of 500k, then preg_match will filter those and extract 95 lines :) amazing

Comment: i'll accept you answer because it's faster for 95% searches, and that's big improvement :) also, do you think if i split .txt files into smaller files this will be even faster?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you reading line by line though you might run out of memory:

> ( might need to tweak your php.ini memory_limit and max_execution_time or run via cli )

```
$rFile = fopen( 'inputfile.txt', 'r' );
$iLineNumber = 0;
$sSearch = '123';
$iLimit  = 5000;
while( !feof( $rFile ) )
{
    if( $iLineNumber > $iLimit )
    {
        break;
    }
    $sLine = fgets( $rFile );
    if( preg_match("/\b$sSearch\b/", $sLine, $aMatches ) ) 
    {
        $aCats[] = $aMatches[ 0 ];
    }
    ++$iLineNumber;
}
var_dump( $aCats );
```

My suggestion would be to **reformat the file into a sql import** and use a database. Flat file search is significantly slower.

> Infile:

```
put-returns-between-paragraphs
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
put-returns-between-paragraphs
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
put-returns-between-paragraphs
123
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
put-returns-between-paragraphs
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
123
put-returns-between-paragraphs
for-linebreak-add-2-spaces-at-end
indent-code-by-4-spaces-indent-code-by-4-spaces
```

> Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

It was wrapping an additional array from matches so we have to use [ 0 ]

Comment: `var_dump( $aCats );` gives me `array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" } }` and i can confirm there are at least 50 matches for `123`

Comment: You need to change the search to be what you want.

Comment: if i put just one line in inputfile.txt `123-test` and search for 123, the result should be 123-test because that's what's on that line, now i get array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "123" } }

Comment: oh boy, oh boy, you have an error, it should be `$aCats[] = $sLine;`  :) :)

Comment: You initially asked for a search filter using the regex provided. Take a look at my edit which shows the input/output while searching for '123'

Comment: you're right, i forgot to add, i'm extracting lines if there is a matching word in that line :)

Comment: after some testing, this is 2-3 slower than foreach :)

Comment: As it should be because it's loading line by line. Ideal for large files that may run php out of memory but not as efficient as loading the entire file contents once into memory.

Comment: yes i see what you did here, you can limit how many lines you want to be seached and this is good thing